# String immutability in CPython violated

Tags: python, string, fuzzy

This is more of an 'interesting' phenomena I encountered in a Python module that I'm trying to understand, rather than a request for help (though a solution would also be useful).

```
>>> import fuzzy
>>> s = fuzzy.Soundex(4)
>>> a = "apple"
>>> b = a
>>> sdx_a = s(a)
>>> sdx_a
'A140'
>>> a
'APPLE'
>>> b
'APPLE'
```

Yeah, so the [fuzzy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy) module totally violates the immutability of strings in Python. Is it able to do this because it is a C-extension? And does this constitute an error in CPython as well as the module, or even a security risk?

Also, can anyone think of a way to get around this behaviour? I would like to be able to keep the original capitalisation of the string.

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the generated C where it mutates the string.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't it mutate it in `__call__` [`__pyx_f_5fuzzy_7Soundex___call__`]?  It declares a cdef char ptr which it sets equal to the result of a PyString_AsString call, and then modifies the contents.

Comment: @DSM: Not in the code in Bitbucket. I only see reads from it, on [line 891](https://bitbucket.org/yougov/fuzzy/src/c210ad2f3f68/src/fuzzy.c#cl-891).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: ah.  I was looking the released version, not trunk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This bug was resolved [back in February](https://bitbucket.org/yougov/fuzzy/issue/1/soundex-modifies-input-argument); update your version.

To answer your question, yes, there are several ways to modify immutable types at the C level. The security implications are unknown, and possibly even unknowable, at this point.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Actually, I used easy_install to install fuzzy only three weeks ago. The version it's giving me is fuzzy-1.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg, and it's this version that has the error.

Comment: @Alex: They don't always keep it up to date there; install from Bitbucket.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the `fuzzy` module available to test right now, but the following creates a string with a new identity:

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> b = ''.join(a)
>>> b
'hello'
>>> id(a), id(b)
(182894286096, 182894559280)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about CPython, but it looks like in `fuzzy.c` it declares `char *cs = s`, where `s` is the input to `__call__`. It then mutates `cs[i]`, which will obviously mutate `s[i]` and therefore the original string. This is definitely a bug with Fuzzy and you should file it on the [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/yougov/fuzzy/issues). As Greg's answer said, using `''.join(a)` will create a new copy.

Comment: It's been filed on Bitbucket. Twice.

Answer (score 0):

If it changes the immutable string, it's a bug, you can walk around this by:

```
s(a.upper())
```